# Override argument passed by URL

Tags: 6, routes, hooks

I think I must be missing something basic. I have a template that is usually called via a URL but I also want to be able to call it manually using theme()

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu().
 */
function signup_menu() {
  $items = array();

  $items['list/signup/success/%'] = array(
    'title' => 'Sign-up Successful',
    'page callback' => 'theme',
    'page arguments' => array(3),
    'page arguments' => array('signup_success'),
  );

  return $items;
}

/**
 * Implements hook_theme().
 */
function signup_theme() {
  return array(
      'signup_success' => array(
      'arguments' => array('node' => NULL),
      'template' => 'signup-success',
    )
  );
}

function signup_preprocess_signup_success(&$variables) {
  $signup = signup_record(arg(3));
  $variables['signup'] = $signup;
}
```

How do I override the argument that is usually passed through the URL? So I can call it like this:

```
theme('signup_success', $signup-id);
```

The preprocess function only ever takes the argument that comes from the current URL which is incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely you will have to change your preprocess hook to replace `arg(3)` that is hard coding it in an aspect and definitely not make it suitable for manual call.

Can you please investigate `$variables` for the value being passed as argument to `theme()`? I hope you will get it there.

Comment: Groan..... it was there in the variables array the whole time. Thanks Shuaib!